# nmap doesn't seem to find all open ports

Tags: debian, virtualbox, nmap

Hi I got a little setup where I have a debian machine running a virtualbox which is also a debian machine.
I installed apache on the guest machine and now want so see if my host can find the service, but it doesn't

On the guest machine I checked with `nmap localhost`, and the result was the following:

```
$ nmap localhost

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2020-05014 19:23 UTC
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00045s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): 127.0.0.1
Not shown: 989 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
21/tcp   open  ftp
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
111/tcp  open  rpcbind
139/tcp  open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp  open  microsoft-ds
631/tcp  open  ipp
3000/tcp open  ppp
3306/tcp open  mysql
6667/tcp open  irc
8181/tcp open  unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.11 seconds
```

apache is also running:

```
$ sudo service apache2 status
 * apache2 is running
```

and is listening on port 80:

```
$ sudo netstat -anp | grep apache
tcp6     0     0  :::80               :::*          LISTEN     3280/apache2
```

Now I want to see if i can see the open ports from remote from the host machine.
Doing a scan I get the following output:

```
$ nmap 10.0.2.15
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-05-14 15:18 EDT
Nmap scan report for 10.0.2.15
Nost is up (0.000039s latency).
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
```

Both sides can ping each other.
It only shows port 22 as open. And the guests firewall settings are the following:

```
# iptables --list
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target    prot opt source          destination
ACCEPT    tcp  --  anywhere        anywhere         tcp dpt:http flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN
ACCEPT    all  -- anywhere         anywhere
ACCEPT    all  -- anywhere         anywhere         ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT    tcp  -- anywhere         anywhere         tcp dpt:ipp
ACCEPT    tcp  -- anywhere         anywhere         tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT    tcp  -- anywhere         anywhere         tcp dpt:6697
ACCEPT    tcp  -- anywhere         anywhere         tcp dpt:ftp
ACCEPT    tcp  -- anywhere         anywhere         tcp dpt:mysql
ACCEPT    tcp  -- anywhere         anywhere         tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT    tcp  -- anywhere         anywhere         tcp dpt:3000
ACCEPT    tcp  -- anywhere         anywhere         tcp dpt:3500
ACCEPT    tcp  -- anywhere         anywhere         tcp dpt:8181
ACCEPT    tcp  -- anywhere         anywhere         tcp dpt:microsoft-ds
ACCEPT    tcp  -- anywhere         anywhere         tcp dpt:ssh

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target    prot opt source          destination
DOCKER-USER all -- anywhere          anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere            anywhere
ACCEPT    all  --   anywhere       anywhere         ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT    all  --   anywhere       anywhere
DOCKER    all  --   anywhere       anywhere
ACCEPT    all  --   anywhere       anywhere
ACCEPT    all  --   anywhere       anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target    prot opt source          destination
```

What am I missing? 
For context: I am using a metsploitable3 Vagrant-box on a kalilinux host.

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086)

Comment: IPv6 scanning is enabled using the `-6` with `nmap`. What does using that option do in your case?

Comment: What mode did you set the network adaptor to in virtual box (in the virtual box settings)?

Comment: Thanks for the edit in hindsight obviously I shouldn't use images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi thanks for the replies. 
By going through it again I narrowed it down to some problem caused by the nested usage of virtualbox and vagrants usage of the bridged network.

I resolved it by altering the use case to working with two VMs in a nat-network. It solved the problem.

Comment: It should also be noted that by default `nmap` does *not* scan all ports, only the 1000 most 'popular' ports and in tcp only, not udp. So you could very well miss out on some ports.

Comment: I am aware of this but it wasn't the problem since nmap didn't even find the Port 80 :P